# Do we have a sample of interest for Graph State Generation?

Tags: graph-states

I'd like to do some tests on Graph State Generation algorithms.

Rather than generating random $CZ$ operator, it would be nice to have a sample online of given circuits.

Comment: What kinds of properties are you looking for?

Comment: Network applicability, possibly.

Comment: But any application would be great!